# How to create a function with variable parameters just like table.insert()?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I know I can use function(a, b, ...) to solve variable parameters problems. But how can I do if I want to create a function like table.insert (table, [pos,] value) ?
Of cause, not in the following way:

```
function (table, pos, value)
    if value == nil then
        pos = value 
        value = nil
    end
    -- do something
end
```

Comment: Why not in the way above?

Answer (score 0):

Lua does not have function overloading or typechecking of arguments, if needed those should be implemented by the one needing. 
Conveying the usage of your function is also up to you.

If you are not satisfied with your provided snippet, you can rewrite it in other manners for example :

```
function(arg1,arg2,arg3)
    tab=arg1
    if not arg3 then
        value=arg2            
        index=#tab+1
    else
        assert(type(arg2)=='numer',"bad argument #2 to 'insert' (number expected, got table)")
        value=arg3
        index=arg2
    end
    table.insert(tab,index,value)
end
```

or:

```
f2=function(a,b)
    --do smth
end
f3=function(a,b,c) end
f=function(...)
    args={...}
    nargin=#args
    if nargin==2 then 
        f2(args[1],args[2]) --one way to use varied arguments
    elseif nargin==3 then
        f3(...) --other one 
    else error("wrong number of arguments")
    end
end
```

I don't recommend you making functions with optional middle positional arguments though. At least not in a language without compile time type check, and even in those as well.

If you really want optional arguments, put them in the table:

```
function(args)
    tab=args.table
    index=args.index or #tab+1
    value=args.value
    --other arguments, options and associated logic here
    table.insert(tab,index,value)
end
```

Comment: thx，someone asked me about the usage of table.insert() but thought there was something wrong that the variable parameter was in the middle. So I just wonder if there is a special usage for variable parameters.